# can we pass values to cucumber runner class annotations from excel file

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

Is it possible to pass values to runner class annotations.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(format={"html:output"},features={"src\\Cucumber\\swift.feature"},tags={"@add"})
```

i want to pass values to "**tags**" options instead of hardcoding it i.e., i want to read @add from excel file.

Comment: checkout Annotation Processing concept in java. Here is a [tutorial](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101)

Comment: When using fixtures defined in excel you may concider using [Fitnesse](http://fitnesse.org/)